# "having a park just steps away from home" or "having a park just steps from home"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Which of the sentence is correct?

- It's great having a park just steps from home.
- It's great having a park just steps away from home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are perfectly acceptable. In this case there is absolutely no difference in meaning.

I would probably expect to hear it without "away" because it's the kind of sentence that might appear in a housing ad, which usually uses fewer words rather than more.